# Se borran los elementos que están en dos JPanels

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo dos Jpanels:

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
```

**Ambos con los mismos componentes**, `p1` está dentro de un `JTabbedPane` y `p2` está dentro de un `Modal Dialog` que se abre cuando pulso un botón. El problema está en que cuando clickeo en el botón y se ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p2, "Agregar elemento", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);
```

Al cerrar el Dialog e ir al tab que contiene los mismos elementos este ya no tiene ninguno, se borraron. No se a que se debe, es como si cada elemento tuviera que estar en un solo Panel. En ese caso, yo necesito tener el mismo diseño pero en varios JPanel diferentes, ¿Tengo que crear nuevo componentes por cada Panel? O ¿hay alguna forma de que no desaparezcan los elementos al mostrarlos en diferentes momentos en contenedores diferentes?

Dejo imágenes por si ayuda a entender el problema:

**Al principio:**[image: Así está al principio en el Tab]

**Al clickear en el botón:**[image: Al clickear en el botón]

**Después de cerrar el Dialog**[image: Después de cerrar el Dialog]

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: `¿Tengo que crear nuevo componentes por cada Panel?` Sí

Comment: Al parecer si! Gracias! Si querés ponelo como respuesta y la marco como correcta así cierro la pregunta. Saludos!